# Is there a way to increase the number of points available for a Custom Faction?

Tags: endless-legend

When Creating a new faction i have a max of 80 points for their benefits. however if i start with the Mazari and Vaulters and try to copy them i need about 125 points, more than the 80 i start off with.

Is there a way to increase my 80 points for creating a custom faction?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a way via legitimate means in game, but someone listed a way on a [Steam Forum](https://steamcommunity.com/app/289130/discussions/0/517141807567332441/) of modifying a text file of the game to allow more points for a custom faction.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Endless Legend\Public\Simulation
>   File is called "FactionTraits[Affinity]" open with notepad and you'll find an "80" listed in the description this is the points you have to work with. Just change this value and go to town. You can also edit the starting gold as well.

It even looks like this may affect online play according to the link if you change this file before starting an online game, but be careful with that.  I'm not sure of the policies that go along with cheating online.

I also found an [additional source](https://www.cheathappens.com/show_board2.asp?headID=123769&titleID=20310) discussing the same thing as well.